# Not able to bind ObservableCollection to DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, itemssource

if I write in C# coding it's ok
such as

```
DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
dg.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dg.ItemsSource = db;
```

where db is

```
public ObservableCollection<Data> db = new ObservableCollection<Data>();

db.Add(new Data { Name = "person1", Description = "sssssss", Price = 15 });
db.Add(new Data { Name = "person2", Description = "okokok", Price = 12 });
```

it will generate columns and data fine..
but if I write in XAML it can't show any thing

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding db}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
```

I can't find the way to binding this collection to DataGrid..
please tell me why

this is my all xaml

```
<Window x:Class="testt.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="Panel">
        <TextBlock Name="count"/>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding db}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>       
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

thank you

Comment: Did you set the `DataContext` of the `Window` or any other child?

Comment: what's item I have to set to DataContext?

Comment: is db calling or not? , debug it..

Comment: db must be a public property, in your case it's a field.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not using MVVM,try this in your code,

```
DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
dg.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
dg.ItemsSource = db;
this.DataContext = this; //or put this line in constructor.
```

where db is

```
public ObservableCollection<Data> db = new ObservableCollection<Data>();

db.Add(new Data { Name = "person1", Description = "sssssss", Price = 15 });
db.Add(new Data { Name = "person2", Description = "okokok", Price = 12 });
```

And in Xaml,

```
<Window x:Class="testt.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="Panel">
        <TextBlock Name="count"/>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding db}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>       
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think you missed the most important part. If you want to use `Binding` you have to set the `DataContext` somewhere on the view. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a good start for the theory of `Binding`.

Usually, you would use a `ViewModel` for that. E.g.

```
public class WndViewModel : ViewModelBase // the base class implementing INotifyPropertyChanged
                                          // although you don't need it for your case 
{
    private ObservableCollection<Data> _db;
    public ObservableCollection<Data> Db 
    { 
        get { return _db ?? (_db = new ObservableCollection<Data>()); 
    }

    public WndViewModel()
    {
        Db.Add(new Data { Name = "person1", Description = "sssssss", Price = 15 });
        Db.Add(new Data { Name = "person2", Description = "okokok", Price = 12 });
    }
}
```

Then you could use the `ViewModel` like this.

```
<Window ...>
    <Window.DataContext>
         <someNs:WndViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Name="Panel">
            <TextBlock Name="count"/>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Db}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>       
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Please note, that this code is only for demonstration purposes and needs to be improved for a good solution.

I also recommend you to get familar with the `MVVM` pattern. You may start by reading [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx) article.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the datacontext of the window to bind the collection with controls under it.

```
ObservableCollection<Data> db = new ObservableCollection<Data>();

 db.Add(new Data { Name = "person1", Description = "sssssss", Price = 15 });
 db.Add(new Data { Name = "person2", Description = "okokok", Price = 12 });

 this.DataContext = db;
```

Now in XAML you only set the binding of itemsource.

```
<DataGrid Name="grdPerson" ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="True"></DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the "DisplayMemberPath" for the DataGrid which is the first thing that should be done after setting the DataSource.

Comment: @SuperMENG have already given ItemsSource and AutoGeneratedColumns=True

Comment: @VimalCK: I think "DisplayMemberPath" is the property which tells the DataGrid to display what property of the collection it is bound to. Just setting the ItemSource doesn't add that property by default

Comment: Did you tried using DisplayMemberPath and Is it working for you?

Comment: No i am not in position to have it checked but I have been through this kind of situation and in those cases i missed using DisplayMemberPath which worked later when i added it.

Comment: I have tried it and it's not working. Here the problem is View not get notified by the datacontext property. So the INotifyPropertyChanged event would raise and intimate the UI layer to update the new value

Comment: DisplayMemberPath, I think it have to be set in each columns part.. but I use AutoGeneratedColumns,... as in C# code, it no need anything else I just tell itemssource and autogeneratedcolumn.. it can show the DataGrid with value properly

Answer (score 0):

You have to Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface inorder to reflect the changes. Please see the below snippet

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace StylingIntroSample
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Data> _db = new ObservableCollection<Data>();

    public ObservableCollection<Data> db {
        get { return _db; }
        set
        {
            _db = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("db");
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        LoadItems();
    }

    private void LoadItems()
    {
        db.Add(new Data { Name = "person1", Description = "sssssss", Price = 15 });
        db.Add(new Data { Name = "person2", Description = "okokok", Price = 12 });
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged!= null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
}
```

}

### In XAML

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                Name="Panel">
        <TextBlock Name="count" />
        <DataGrid Name="MyGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding db}"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your all help
now the problem solved!

the db should be property, not field so I change a little code to be

```
public ObservableCollection<Data> db { set; get; }
```

and I have to set DataContext with this sentense

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

now it can work properly :)